# Weird things on the graph of the function $1/sin(y-x)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $F(x,y)=1/sin(y-x)$

We can easily compute the right limit of $F$ on ${y=x-\pi}$ we find $-\infty$

and the left limit of $F$ on ${y=x-\pi}$ we find $+\infty$

but when we plot this function we find something weird it seems like the right and the left limit of $F$ on ${y=x-\pi}$ is $-\infty$!!!!!

can anyone explain to me this thing?

Comment: divergent we know, only to care about is sign of it, what is graph of $sinx$?

Comment: yes divergent ,but if you can plot the geometric interpretation of the limits are not the same with the graph of the function

Comment: Not when I plot it. How did you plot it? Can you include a screenshot or something?

Comment: thanks, @HansLundmark Lundmark, it will be very helpful if you can include a screenshot

Comment: I can't attach screenshots in the comments, but I just typed "plot 1/sin(y-x)" into Google. Or else try WA: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fsin%28y-x%29

Comment: thanks, now I am sure there is a problem in the logiciel and not in my interpretation